# Information about free account Azure and SQL database

Tags: azure, azure-sql

I'm using free account and I need to create an instance of SQL database. I have read there is 250 GB of instance S0 Standard of SQL database with 10 DTU in the free tier for 12 months. But, when I try to create it tells me that the estimated cost is 12.65€.

[image: Photo of the screen]

Answer (score 0):

This is a good article with a lot of details about the free trial and offer you are referring to: [link](https://dev.to/azure/azure-free-account-is-it-really-free-53cb)

In the comments there is people confirming even though those services included appear to not be free you will not be charged. I know, confusing but remember this is Microsoft...

Also, you should get $200 credit for the first 30 days in case by mistake you create something that is chargeable it consumes from that...